# Does $\mu(A\cap B) = \mu(A \cup B)$ mean $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$ ?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Does it implies so ? I am confused whether measure equality imply set equality

Comment: Your question confuses set equality with measure equality.  Using the usual measure on the reals, if $A=(0,1), B=(0,1) \cup \{2\}$ we have $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$ but $A \neq B$

Comment: Or $(0,1)$ versus $[0,1]$.

Comment: But you do have equality up to a null set, and $\mu(A \Delta B)$ is a metric on the finite measure subsets modulo null sets

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what comparison do you know between $\mu(A \cap B)$ and $\mu(A)$?  The same principle can be used four times to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
\mu(B)\geq\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A\cup B)\geq\mu(A).
$$
So $\mu(B)\geq\mu(A)$. Reversing roles, $\mu(A)\geq\mu(B)$, and so $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

The union and intersection of sets $A,B$ having the same measure means the symmetric set difference has zero measure; it *may* be empty or *may* be a null set.   Thus the sets may not be identical, (but yes, they do have the same measure).

$$\mu(A\cap B)=\mu (A\cup B) \implies \mu(A\Delta B)=0, \mu(A)=\mu(B)$$

Comment: But it implies that $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$ right ?